# Compression for short number strings

Tags: compression

Does anyone know of a compression for very short number/binary strings?

For example, I would like to compress any numbers (0-9) or binary of i.e. 3,2,6,4
or
I would like to compress numbers or binary of 2,1,3,6,1,4,13

Applied to pick 4 and euromillions study.

Answer (score 0):

I looked up EuroMillions and Pick 4. I see that the former ranges from 1-50 and the latter is 0-9. I think we can assume any number is equally probable (some compression schemes exploit the fact that certain numbers are more likely to occur than others).

What platform are you coding on? A high level language like Python or JavaScript? Or a lower level language like C or C++? Are you hoping to store a large set of number sequences? Or are you just trying to come up with an efficient in-memory representation?

The most reasonable trade-off you could make if you wanted to work with a large set in memory is to make sure that each character is represented by no more than 1 byte (which can hold values from 0-255). That might be harder to do in higher level languages which often just have a "number" type without any finer granularity. But C/C++ or even Java should allow you to do this.

If you wanted to store a large set of these equally probable numbers on disc, look at the minimum number of bits required to store a number. For EuroMillions, you would need 6 bits to store a number (2^6 = 64). Then store them in a bitstream in order to save 2 bits per number. With Pick 4, you could encode 2 numbers in a single byte.